# dynamically delete canvas elements by tags

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi i am working on a project where i am using canvas to place squares(current placeholder). at a specific point within the canvas. I am also using tagging on each fillRect call.

my code consists of two simple files...
canvas.html

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    canvas{border: .5px solid #333333;}
</style>
<body>
<div class ="flex justify-between">
    <div class ="tag-placement">
    <p>Enter A Name For The Tag</p>
    <input id="tagName" type="text" placeholder="enter a unique name for the tag" >
  </div>
  <div class ="tag-placement">
    <p>Type The Name Of The Tag To Delete</p>
    <input id="delTagName" type="text" placeholder="enter a unique name for the tag" onchange="deleteTag()" >
  </div>
</div>
        <canvas>




    </canvas>

</body>
<script src="canvas.js"  ></script>
</html>
```

And the accompanying Javascript file

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var c  = canvas.getContext('2d');
var xpos
var ypos
var tagname

document.addEventListener("dblclick",()=>{
var tagname = document.getElementById("tagName").value
var x = event.offsetX;
var y = event.offsetY;
var xpos = x;
var ypos = y;
c.fillRect(x,y,20,20, tags = tagname);
console.log(x,y,tagname);
});

function deleteTag(){
var tagN = document.getElementById("delTagName").value;
canvas.delete('tagN')

}
```

My question: Is there a simple way to delete the rectangles by the tag ?

Comment: Refer to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800845/dynamically-remove-elements-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The [.fillRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) accepts 4 parameters so the last tagname parameter is not doing any thing.

Here is another way to achieve a similar result:

Make an array to keep track of of all the shapes that you created:

```js
let shapes = []
```

To add a new shape to the canvas, make an object with all the shape information and add that object to the array of shapes:

```js
const newShape = {
  tagname: tagname,
  x: e.offsetX,
  y: e.offsetY,
  w: 20,
  h: 20,
}

shapes.push(newShape)
```

Now make a render function to clear the canvas and then draw all the shapes that are stored in the shapes array:

```js
function render() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  for (let shape of shapes) {
    c.fillRect(shape.x, shape.y, shape.w, shape.h)
  }
}
```

And when you want to delete a shape from the canvas, get the shape tagname and simply filter the shapes array and remove the tagname of the shape that must be deleted and then run the render function to clear the canvas and re-draw all the remaining shapes:

```js
const delTag = document.getElementById('delTagName')
delTag.addEventListener('change', deleteTag)

function deleteTag() {
  shapes = shapes.filter(shape => shape.tagname !== delTag.value)
  render()
}
```

Here is an working example:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
var c = canvas.getContext('2d')

let shapes = []

document.addEventListener('dblclick', e => {
  var tagname = document.getElementById('tagName').value
  if (!tagname) {
    alert('Enter a tagname')
    return
  }

  if (shapes.findIndex(shape => shape.tagname == tagname) !== -1) {
    alert('tagname already used')
    return
  }

  const newShape = {
    tagname: tagname,
    x: e.offsetX,
    y: e.offsetY,
    w: 20,
    h: 20,
  }

  shapes.push(newShape)
  render()
})

function render() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  for (let shape of shapes) {
    c.fillRect(shape.x, shape.y, shape.w, shape.h)
  }
}

const delTag = document.getElementById('delTagName')
delTag.addEventListener('change', deleteTag)

function deleteTag() {
  shapes = shapes.filter(shape => shape.tagname !== delTag.value)
  render()
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 0.5px solid #333333;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tag-placement {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4px;
}

input,
p {
  margin: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tag-placement">
    <p>Add TagName:</p>
    <input id="tagName" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="tag-placement">
    <p>Delete TagName:</p>
    <input id="delTagName" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<canvas width="530px" height="120px"> </canvas>
```